What's the fastest way to compute an 3D IDCT for a subset of indices
I have a 3D tensor (200x200x200) in the Fourier domain and I'm trying to compute the real (spatial) values of a subset of the indices (~8000).
Computing the entire inverse transform is too computationally expensive. The classical algorithm for finding a single index in the tensor is relatively quick for 1 index but grows at O(n^6). Other algorithms like row-column-frame or radix algorithms compute the entire tensor efficiently but from what I understand do not scale down to subsets of indices.
Is there any faster way to compute the IDCT of a set of "random" (random in the sense that its not every even index, just indices sprinkled throughout the tensor) indices than to classically compute each index in the subset?
I work in Fortran 77
I've tried using the classical algorithm, 3D Vector Radix, Row-Column-Frame, Fast Cosine Transforms using the FFT. Using the classical algorithm is the only one that seems to work. Other "faster" methods do the entire tensor and can't compute just a subset (in a reasonable amount of time).
